# FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPORTED (0x8cdd)

Tags: opengl, frame-buffer

I've tried to implement bloom following this [tutorial](http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Bloom). But everytime I get the framebuffer object error 0x8cdd, which I believe means FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPORTED. I'm pretty sure the problem occures because of the  GL_RGB16F format. But for HDR I need more precision than GL_RGB. Does somebody know how to fix this issue?

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &hdrFBO);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, hdrFBO);

    glGenTextures(2, hdrColorBuffers);
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, hdrColorBuffers[i]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, 0);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  // We clamp to the edge as the blur filter would otherwise sample repeated texture values!
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        // attach texture to framebuffer
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, hdrColorBuffers[i], 0);
    }

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepth);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
    // - Tell OpenGL which color attachments we'll use (of this framebuffer) for rendering
    GLuint attachments[2] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
    glDrawBuffers(2, attachments);
    // - Finally check if framebuffer is complete
    GLenum  status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
        printf("Framebuffer hdr fail: 0x%x\n", status);
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // bloom framebuffer

    glGenFramebuffers(2, bloomFBO);
    glGenTextures(2, bloomColorBuffers);
    for(GLuint i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, bloomFBO[i]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bloomColorBuffers[i]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, bloomColorBuffers[i], 0);

        GLenum  status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
        if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
            printf("Framebuffer bloom fail: 0x%x\n", status);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **GL_RGBA16F** instead of **GL_RGB16F**.

It's likely the GPU can't render to 48bit buffers.